# Javascript Growth Population Problem: Code Returning Wrong Answer

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, rate

I have the following problem:

In a small town the population is `p0 = 1000` at the beginning of a year. The population regularly increases by 2 percent per year and moreover 50 new inhabitants per year come to live in the town. How many years does the town need to see its population greater or equal to `p = 1200` inhabitants?

Below is my code:

```
function nbYear(p0, percent, aug, p) {    
  for (var i=0; p0 < p; i++){
    p0 = p0 * (1 + percent/100) + aug;     
    return i
  }
}        
nbYear(1000, 2, 50, 1200)
```

My solution returns 0 which is wrong. The correct answer is 3. I know if I removed the `{}`, it will give me the right answer. But I want to understand what is wrong with my code. Why is it returning 0?

Comment: your return statement is exiting the loop. why do you need a loop for 1 iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the value of p0 (increased population) and return `i` based on that.

```
function nbYear(p0, percent, aug, p) {

  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    if (p0 >= p) {return i;}
    p0 = p0 * (1 + percent/100) + aug; i++;
  }
}
nbYear(1000, 2, 50, 1200)
```

In order to understand what is wrong with your code, you need to understand how `return` statement & `for` loop work. If you return the value of `i` inside the loop without any condition, the return statement is executed no matter what. So your function will always return the initial value of `i` that is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nbYear(p0, percent, aug, p) {

var population_perc = p0 * percent/100;

population_total = p0 + (population_perc) + aug ;

var number_of_years = 1;

while(population_total < p)
{        

    population_perc = population_total * percent/100;
        population_total = population_total + population_perc + aug;
        number_of_years += 1;
    
 }
          
        return number_of_years;
}
```

Go through the above code and you'll understand what's wrong. You can't use "return" inside a for loop. That's what is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

`const nbYear = (p0, percent, aug, p, year=0) => p0 >= p ? year : nbYear(p0 + Math.round(p0 * percent / 100) + aug, percent, aug, p, year + 1)`

Super refactored version. Not my original art.

I believe `math.round` makes this dynamic enough for not whole percentages? ex..(2.6%). Is someone can break this one down as to how exactly it fixes the problem, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30144355)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare & return i outside of the loop.
Just like that:

```
function nbYear(p0, percent, aug, p) {
  let i = 0;
  for (i; p0 < p; i++) {
    p0 += p0 * (percent / 100) + aug;
  }
  return i;
}
```

I hope it helps. ;-)